# Node Js and Concurrency. Is it faster than Tomcat?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, rest, express

I am trying to understand "In node js everything runs in parallel except your code" statement. So I decided to give it a try. I have a restful service which I am running on my tomcat local server.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String ping() throws InterruptedException {
        //Simulation for background processing
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        return "Hi I am Tomcat Ping Service";
    }
```

Similarly I have NodeJs restful api also running on my local.

```
app.get('/nodeTest', function(req, res){
    var options = {
         host: '192.168.1.8',
         port : 8080,
         path : '/TestNode/rest/ping'
    };
    http.get(options, function(resp) {
      console.log("Got response: " + resp.statusCode);
      res.send("Inside Node JS Ping Service.");
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
});
```

I am invoking node restservice from my browser which in turn invoking restservice on tomcat.
To check nodejs concurrency I hit http://localhost:3000/nodeTest in two tabs after two second delay.
First call response I got after 10.03 seconds, while second response took 18.01 seconds.

This result I was not expecting as node assign a callback function, whenever the request completes it executes the callback function(in the mean time it can process other requests.), So when first request came after assigning the callback to that request, it should have taken the second request instead of waiting for first request to complete.
Hence, ideally second call should have taken close to 10 seconds to complete.

**This raises the question how node js is faster than traditional request per thread model**.

Edit:-

I am using node eclipse plugin to run nodeJS and simple SpringMVC rest service to run rest service on Tomcat.

Identified the root cause it was issue of chrome, chrome is stalling the request hence the second call is delayed.

Request time taken[image: Time Taken]
[image]

But when I tried one request from firefox and one from chrome it worked.

Below are the logs :-
Node Server:-

```
Request Entry time in Node JS :: Sun Jul 19 2015 21:57:39 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Request Entry time in Node JS :: Sun Jul 19 2015 21:57:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Got response: 200
Time Taken in seconds :: 10.004
[90mGET /nodeTest [32m200 [90m10004ms - 28b[0m
Got response: 200
Time Taken in seconds :: 10.005
```

Tomcat Server :-

```
Thread Entry time in Tomcat :: http-8080-1 :: Sun Jul 19 21:57:39 EDT 2015
Thread Entry time in Tomcat :: http-8080-2 :: Sun Jul 19 21:57:45 EDT 2015
Time taken by thread :: http-8080-1 :: 10
Time taken by thread :: http-8080-2 :: 10
```

Not sure why chrome was stalling call.

Comment: This seems strange indeed. Can you check to see when the two Tomcat threads are created?  I.e concurrently or in series.  Maybe use an `AtomicInteger` and `Thread.setName`. Or just return the start and end time strings in `ping`.

Comment: You must have some synchronization block or bottleneck somewhere. Are you showing us all the code?